# Understanding decorator behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I want to understand the decorator behaviour in this code

`abc.py`

```
def my_decorator_module(some_function):
    def wrapper():
        num = 10
        if num == 10:
            print('yess')
        else:
            print('no')

        some_function()

        print('print after some_function() called')

    return wrapper()
```

and call this function as decorator

`x.py`

```
from abc import my_decorator_module

@my_decorator_module
def just_some_function():
    print("Wheee!")
```

output is

```
yess
Wheee!
print after some_function() called
```

event I did not call `just_some_function()` in x.py file when I execute the x.py file return me output, why?

Answer (score 3):

Because you've called `wrapper` before returning it from your outer decoration function. Don't do that.

```
return wrapper   # not wrapper()
```

The [tutorial you're following](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/) had earlier introduced the concept of returning *functions* rather than calling them and returning their results; that's what you need to be doing here.

Answer (score 2):

You did not explicitely called `just_some_function()` but your "decorator" does, cf the last line:

```
def my_decorator_module(some_function):
    def wrapper():
        num = 10
        if num == 10:
            print('yess')
        else:
            print('no')

        some_function()

        print('print after some_function() called')

    # here !!!   
    return wrapper()
```

This is actually a faulty implementation - your decorator should not return the result of calling `wrapper`, but return the `wrapper` function itself:

```
    return wrapper
```

If you don't understand why: the `@decorator` syntax is only syntaxic sugar so this:

```
@decorator
def somefunc():
    print("somefunc")
```

is actually only a shortcut for this:

```
def somefunc():
    print("somefunc")

somefunc = decorator(somefunc)
```

so your decorator has to return a function object (or any callable FWIW), usually - but not necessarily - some wrapper that will take care of calling the decorated function (and preferably returning the result).